# What is the Spring MVC Hibernate application design?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I learnt Spring MVC few weeks ago, and I want to put this into practice now.

I am about to build an applications that interacts heavily with the database, My question is:

What is the best practice to build a spring mvc 4 application with Hibernate 4, Should I use this design pattern?

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or should I use Spring Data JPA instead?

P.S. I tried to make the question not so general.

Thanks already.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA eliminates a lot of the boilerplate code you might need to write for your DAOs, so it is convenient. http://www.mkyong.com/ has good tutorials.

JPA is useful in that you can (somewhat) easily change ORMs, for example if you wanted to switch to EclipseLink down the road.

Regarding package names, I usually use:

```
com.example.project.
    domain          (JPA entities)
    repository      (SDR JPA repos)
    service         (service classes)
    web
        controller  (Spring MVC Controllers)
        exception   (Custom http exception classes)
        form        (Form backing objects)
        interceptor (HandlerInterceptors)
        validation  (Web-specific validation classes)
```

Down the road though, you might use a Maven multi-module project and break web into its own module.

Comment: any good tutorial about Spring Data JPA that can help me? and regarding hibernate which structure(from the 2 images) is the best practice?